# Wrong path when including files

Tags: php

I'm requiring some files and having trouble getting the paths correct.

Here is my current folder and file structure:
[image]

So I have defined some constants in the config.php like this:

```
define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/views');
define('TEMPLATE_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/views/templates');
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost:8080/site');
```

The start.php only contains the database connection.

To the admin_header.php I added these two files:

```
require APP_ROOT . '/config.php';
require APP_ROOT . '/start.php';
```

So I want to add these two files to the admin_header.php so later I only have to require the header files in other places.

When I require the files below in admin/index.php

```
require TEMPLATE_ROOT . '/admin_header.php';
require VIEW_ROOT . '/admin/index.php';
require TEMPLATE_ROOT . '/admin_footer.php';
```

I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant TEMPLATE_ROOT - assumed 'TEMPLATE_ROOT' in F:\wamp64\www\site\admin\index.php on line 2

Warning: require(TEMPLATE_ROOT/admin_header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\wamp64\www\site\admin\index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'TEMPLATE_ROOT/admin_header.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in F:\wamp64\www\site\admin\index.php on line 2
```

Comment: Are you calling `config.php` before `index.php`? (Or including inside index.php)

Comment: **Chicken&Egg Paradox**: You are including `require APP_ROOT . '/config.php';` but in the `config.php` you are first-time define `APP_ROOT` constant. Big logic issue. `admin/index.php` should first include `config.php` like `require '../app/config.php';`

Comment: @Antonis: require VIEW_ROOT . '/admin/index.php'; is the view of the main admin/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I think none of your files are really loaded since you have :

```
require APP_ROOT . '/config.php';
```

and config.php **contains** : `define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);`

Change it to, and it should work :

```
require  __DIR__ . '/config.php';
```

Comment: did you change all of your  `APP_ROOT` to `__DIR__` ?

Comment: Do you mean in config.php or in admin_header.php or in both?

Comment: `APP_ROOT` is unknown to the script since it's only declared in your config.php, you have to change it prior to its usage, or simply get rid of it and use `__DIR__` instead.